# duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_followuser"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class FollowUserModel(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='followers')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='following')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
 constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['author', 'profile'],name='unique_followuser')]
```

What i want to do is basically i want an asymmetrical follow function. Like if:
user1 follows user2,
user2 should be able to follow user1 too.

But the problem is that when user1 follows user2,user2 can't follow user1 asymmetrically because of unique constraint.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

ManyToMany filed will solve your unique constraint problem:

- docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

example solution:

```py
---
author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user')
followers = models.ManyToMany(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='followers')
---
```